# Event scheduler in mysql runs every 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql

Event scheduler in mysql runs every 1 minute

```
CREATE EVENT `user_created_this_month_schedule` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2018-08-31 15:35:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE 
ENABLE

DO update user_data set user_created_this_month = 0 where user_data_id = 7
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: _It's not working_ ?? Whats not working, please be a little more specific????

Comment: @RiggsFolly it doesn't set value of user_created_this_month to  0, is that query correct or need modification

Comment: it's working now,
problem is in trigger on that table

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler="ON"; 
CREATE EVENT `user_created_this_month_schedule` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2018-08-31 15:35:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE user_data SET user_created_this_month = 0 WHERE user_data_id = 7;
SHOW EVENTS;
```

Comment: Thanx for your comment but it's working now
Problem is in Trigger which i have applied on that table :cheers